# Why C# CultureInfo.CurrentCulture give en_US in Window-7 Japanese culture?

Tags: c#, windows, internationalization, cultureinfo

I have window-7 Ultimate OS.I written below code for get current culture info.

```
        void TestMessage()
        {
            CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            CultureInfo culture1 = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        }
```

it is working fine with window-8,server 2012 Japanese OS. But it is not working in window-7 only. Please look below image of my computer region setting[image]

Can any anyone guide me to get correct culture name?

Thanks,

Comment: what does `CurrentUICulture` give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture.

- CurrentCulture: formatting of data (numbers, dates), it is configured in Windows using the tab visible in your screenshot
- CurrentUICulture: the language to speak/write to your user, it is configured in Windows using one of the other tabs showing in your screenshot. ("Keyboard & Languages" I think)

Your screenshot:

- ... is showing american numeric notation because *CurrentCulture* is set to en-US
- ... is talking Japanese because *CurrentUICulture* is very likely set to Japanese

So, if you need to know what language to use for localization, as is probably your case, you should be using CurrentUICulture.